# By entering latitude and longitude how to check at which circle it is nearest to

Tags: oracle-spatial

[image: this is my circle table]

```
INSERT INTO circle_ (
circle_geometry,
latitude,
longitude
) VALUES (
sdo_geometry(2003,  -- two-dimensional polygon
 NULL, NULL, sdo_elem_info_array(1, 1003, 4), -- one circle
 sdo_ordinate_array(8, 7, 10, 9, 8, 11)),
77.45,
77.89
);
```

I have added a circle and let suppose there are three circles, now I want to check which circle is nearest to me by entering my latitude and longitude.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I've mentioned what i have tried, further on i want help to proceed. thanx